# How do I make this if statment into a switch statement?

Tags: java, if-statement, case

Hi I'm a beginner to java, and I did my research before and found nothing that could help my problem my issue. So how am I able to convert the bottom if statement into a switch statement?

```
if (!lengthTest(newPassword)) {
                printerrormessage(1);
            } // new password fails the only letter and digits test
            else if (!onlyLettersAndDigitsTest(newPassword)) {
                printerrormessage(2);
            } else if (!containsoneToThreeDigitsTest(newPassword)) {
                printerrormessage(3);
            } else if (!differentThanLastTwoPasswordsTest(PREVIOUS1, PREVIOUS2, newPassword)) {
                printerrormessage(4);
            } else { // New password passed all the tests if end up here
                System.out.println("Your password was successfully updated");
                validPassword = true;
            }

public static void printErrorMessage (int errorCode) {
        
    if (errorCode == 1) {
        System.out.print("Password does not meet requirement: must be between 6 and 15 characters");
        
    } else if (errorCode == 2) {
        System.out.print("Password does not meet requirement: must contain only letters and digits");
        
    } else if (errorCode == 3 ) {
        System.out.print("Password does not meet requirement: must contain at least 1 digit and not more than 3");
        
    } else if (errorCode == 4 ) {
        System.out.print("Password does not meet requirement: must be different than previous 2 passwords");
    
    
    
    }
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html should be clear enough. What is it you don't understand about how `switch` works? Notice that page contains an almost identical example of how to convert a series of `if` statements to a `switch`

Answer (score 1):

All your if-conditions are mutually exclusive, good. All of them check the same variable, good. All of them are using a primitive value to compare against, good. All of them compare for equality with `==`, good.

The variable becomes the variable in `switch(variable)` and the values to compare against become the `case value:` labels:

```
public static void printErrorMessage (int errorCode) {
    switch (errorCode) {
      case 1:
        System.out.print("Password does not meet requirement: must be between 6 and 15 characters");
        break;
      case 2:
        // System.out.print(...
        break;
      // other cases ...
    }
}
```

Don't forget to add `break`, otherwise subsequent "case"s will be executed as well!